# How a simple and harmless left join can make a query so slow?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Why a simple and "harmless" LEFT JOIN on a specific table can make so much difference in the performance result? I have a primary table "mposicao" in the query that relate itself on two more tables on a left join, one of the two tables related, if alone, the query takes just 9.041 ms to give the results, in this case I'm talking on "mposicao_telemetria", but when I add the second table "mposicao_rastreador" it twists the whole query by taking 68726.797 ms to give the results, the thing is that both of the related tables have foreign keys correctly configured and both are indexing the foreign key, so why the difference in the performance and the planning execution of the query, the two tables have the same number of rows and the second related table that is giving trouble has even less columns than the first related table that works just fine.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE VERBOSE
  SELECT *
    FROM mposicao mp
    LEFT JOIN mposicao_telemetria mt ON mp.id_posicao = mt.id_posicao
    LEFT JOIN mposicao_rastreador mpr ON mp.id_posicao = mpr.id_posicao
  WHERE
    mp.id_veiculo = 508
    AND mp.dt_gps >= TIMESTAMP '2014-05-29 00:00'
    AND mp.dt_gps <= TIMESTAMP '2014-05-29 09:03'
    AND mp.bl_ativo = true
  ORDER BY mp.dt_gps DESC, mp.dt_servidor DESC
  LIMIT 10;
```

The analyze result for the query above is 68726.797 ms: http://explain.depesz.com/s/l7M

```
 Limit  (cost=760284.22..760284.24 rows=10 width=269) (actual time=68726.570..68726.572 rows=10 loops=1)
       Output: mp.id_posicao, mp.id_veiculo, mp.id_login, mp.id_equip, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor, mp.nr_lat, mp.nr_lon, mp.nr_direcao, mp.nr_velocidade, mp.nr_dpercorr, mp.nr_azimute, mp.nr_raio, mp.bl_poschave, mp.bl_porta, mp.bl_bloqueado, mp.bl_sirene, mp.bl_setas, mp.bl_panico, mp.bl_excesso_vel, mp.bl_cerca, mp.bl_desenergizado, mp.nr_evento, mp.bl_entrada_1, mp.bl_entrada_2, mp.bl_entrada_3, mp.bl_entrada_4, mp.bl_entrada_5, mp.bl_entrada_6, mp.bl_saida_1, mp.bl_saida_2, mp.bl_saida_3, mp.bl_saida_4, mp.bl_saida_5, mp.bl_saida_6, mp.nr_satelites, mp.bl_ativo, mp.bl_gprs, mp.bl_memory, mp.bl_excesso_rpm, mp.input1, mp.input2, mp.input3, mp.input4, mp.input5, mp.input6, mp.input7, mp.input8, mp.input9, mt.id_posicao_telemetria, mt.id_posicao, mt.nr_rpm, mt.nr_horimetro, mt.dt_last_update, mt.bl_ativo, mt.id_pessoa, mt.nr_temperatura1, mt.nr_temperatura2, mt.nr_temperatura3, mt.nr_vel_sensor, mt.nr_horimetro_revalidate, mt.nr_gprs_quality, mt.nr_direction, mpr.id_posicao_rastreador, mpr.id_posicao, mpr.nr_voltagem_main, mpr.nr_voltagem_backup, mpr.dt_last_update, mpr.bl_ativo, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor
   ->  Sort  (cost=760284.22..760284.28 rows=26 width=269) (actual time=68726.568..68726.570 rows=10 loops=1)
         Output: mp.id_posicao, mp.id_veiculo, mp.id_login, mp.id_equip, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor, mp.nr_lat, mp.nr_lon, mp.nr_direcao, mp.nr_velocidade, mp.nr_dpercorr, mp.nr_azimute, mp.nr_raio, mp.bl_poschave, mp.bl_porta, mp.bl_bloqueado, mp.bl_sirene, mp.bl_setas, mp.bl_panico, mp.bl_excesso_vel, mp.bl_cerca, mp.bl_desenergizado, mp.nr_evento, mp.bl_entrada_1, mp.bl_entrada_2, mp.bl_entrada_3, mp.bl_entrada_4, mp.bl_entrada_5, mp.bl_entrada_6, mp.bl_saida_1, mp.bl_saida_2, mp.bl_saida_3, mp.bl_saida_4, mp.bl_saida_5, mp.bl_saida_6, mp.nr_satelites, mp.bl_ativo, mp.bl_gprs, mp.bl_memory, mp.bl_excesso_rpm, mp.input1, mp.input2, mp.input3, mp.input4, mp.input5, mp.input6, mp.input7, mp.input8, mp.input9, mt.id_posicao_telemetria, mt.id_posicao, mt.nr_rpm, mt.nr_horimetro, mt.dt_last_update, mt.bl_ativo, mt.id_pessoa, mt.nr_temperatura1, mt.nr_temperatura2, mt.nr_temperatura3, mt.nr_vel_sensor, mt.nr_horimetro_revalidate, mt.nr_gprs_quality, mt.nr_direction, mpr.id_posicao_rastreador, mpr.id_posicao, mpr.nr_voltagem_main, mpr.nr_voltagem_backup, mpr.dt_last_update, mpr.bl_ativo, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor
         Sort Key: mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB
         ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=378522.63..760283.65 rows=26 width=269) (actual time=40387.302..68725.334 rows=575 loops=1)
               Output: mp.id_posicao, mp.id_veiculo, mp.id_login, mp.id_equip, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor, mp.nr_lat, mp.nr_lon, mp.nr_direcao, mp.nr_velocidade, mp.nr_dpercorr, mp.nr_azimute, mp.nr_raio, mp.bl_poschave, mp.bl_porta, mp.bl_bloqueado, mp.bl_sirene, mp.bl_setas, mp.bl_panico, mp.bl_excesso_vel, mp.bl_cerca, mp.bl_desenergizado, mp.nr_evento, mp.bl_entrada_1, mp.bl_entrada_2, mp.bl_entrada_3, mp.bl_entrada_4, mp.bl_entrada_5, mp.bl_entrada_6, mp.bl_saida_1, mp.bl_saida_2, mp.bl_saida_3, mp.bl_saida_4, mp.bl_saida_5, mp.bl_saida_6, mp.nr_satelites, mp.bl_ativo, mp.bl_gprs, mp.bl_memory, mp.bl_excesso_rpm, mp.input1, mp.input2, mp.input3, mp.input4, mp.input5, mp.input6, mp.input7, mp.input8, mp.input9, mt.id_posicao_telemetria, mt.id_posicao, mt.nr_rpm, mt.nr_horimetro, mt.dt_last_update, mt.bl_ativo, mt.id_pessoa, mt.nr_temperatura1, mt.nr_temperatura2, mt.nr_temperatura3, mt.nr_vel_sensor, mt.nr_horimetro_revalidate, mt.nr_gprs_quality, mt.nr_direction, mpr.id_posicao_rastreador, mpr.id_posicao, mpr.nr_voltagem_main, mpr.nr_voltagem_backup, mpr.dt_last_update, mpr.bl_ativo, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor
               Hash Cond: (mpr.id_posicao = mp.id_posicao)
               ->  Seq Scan on public.mposicao_rastreador mpr  (cost=0.00..320161.83 rows=16426383 width=41) (actual time=5.613..31091.401 rows=16417112 loops=1)
                     Output: mpr.id_posicao_rastreador, mpr.id_posicao, mpr.nr_voltagem_main, mpr.nr_voltagem_backup, mpr.dt_last_update, mpr.bl_ativo
               ->  Hash  (cost=378522.30..378522.30 rows=26 width=228) (actual time=35838.996..35838.996 rows=575 loops=1)
                     Output: mp.id_posicao, mp.id_veiculo, mp.id_login, mp.id_equip, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor, mp.nr_lat, mp.nr_lon, mp.nr_direcao, mp.nr_velocidade, mp.nr_dpercorr, mp.nr_azimute, mp.nr_raio, mp.bl_poschave, mp.bl_porta, mp.bl_bloqueado, mp.bl_sirene, mp.bl_setas, mp.bl_panico, mp.bl_excesso_vel, mp.bl_cerca, mp.bl_desenergizado, mp.nr_evento, mp.bl_entrada_1, mp.bl_entrada_2, mp.bl_entrada_3, mp.bl_entrada_4, mp.bl_entrada_5, mp.bl_entrada_6, mp.bl_saida_1, mp.bl_saida_2, mp.bl_saida_3, mp.bl_saida_4, mp.bl_saida_5, mp.bl_saida_6, mp.nr_satelites, mp.bl_ativo, mp.bl_gprs, mp.bl_memory, mp.bl_excesso_rpm, mp.input1, mp.input2, mp.input3, mp.input4, mp.input5, mp.input6, mp.input7, mp.input8, mp.input9, mt.id_posicao_telemetria, mt.id_posicao, mt.nr_rpm, mt.nr_horimetro, mt.dt_last_update, mt.bl_ativo, mt.id_pessoa, mt.nr_temperatura1, mt.nr_temperatura2, mt.nr_temperatura3, mt.nr_vel_sensor, mt.nr_horimetro_revalidate, mt.nr_gprs_quality, mt.nr_direction
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 97kB
                     ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=115.92..378522.30 rows=26 width=228) (actual time=13671.753..35835.286 rows=575 loops=1)
                           Output: mp.id_posicao, mp.id_veiculo, mp.id_login, mp.id_equip, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor, mp.nr_lat, mp.nr_lon, mp.nr_direcao, mp.nr_velocidade, mp.nr_dpercorr, mp.nr_azimute, mp.nr_raio, mp.bl_poschave, mp.bl_porta, mp.bl_bloqueado, mp.bl_sirene, mp.bl_setas, mp.bl_panico, mp.bl_excesso_vel, mp.bl_cerca, mp.bl_desenergizado, mp.nr_evento, mp.bl_entrada_1, mp.bl_entrada_2, mp.bl_entrada_3, mp.bl_entrada_4, mp.bl_entrada_5, mp.bl_entrada_6, mp.bl_saida_1, mp.bl_saida_2, mp.bl_saida_3, mp.bl_saida_4, mp.bl_saida_5, mp.bl_saida_6, mp.nr_satelites, mp.bl_ativo, mp.bl_gprs, mp.bl_memory, mp.bl_excesso_rpm, mp.input1, mp.input2, mp.input3, mp.input4, mp.input5, mp.input6, mp.input7, mp.input8, mp.input9, mt.id_posicao_telemetria, mt.id_posicao, mt.nr_rpm, mt.nr_horimetro, mt.dt_last_update, mt.bl_ativo, mt.id_pessoa, mt.nr_temperatura1, mt.nr_temperatura2, mt.nr_temperatura3, mt.nr_vel_sensor, mt.nr_horimetro_revalidate, mt.nr_gprs_quality, mt.nr_direction
                           Hash Cond: (mt.id_posicao = mp.id_posicao)
                           ->  Seq Scan on public.mposicao_telemetria mt  (cost=0.00..321570.01 rows=15156301 width=100) (actual time=4.370..33948.739 rows=15692493 loops=1)
                                 Output: mt.id_posicao_telemetria, mt.id_posicao, mt.nr_rpm, mt.nr_horimetro, mt.dt_last_update, mt.bl_ativo, mt.id_pessoa, mt.nr_temperatura1, mt.nr_temperatura2, mt.nr_temperatura3, mt.nr_vel_sensor, mt.nr_horimetro_revalidate, mt.nr_gprs_quality, mt.nr_direction
                           ->  Hash  (cost=115.60..115.60 rows=26 width=128) (actual time=1.186..1.186 rows=575 loops=1)
                                 Output: mp.id_posicao, mp.id_veiculo, mp.id_login, mp.id_equip, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor, mp.nr_lat, mp.nr_lon, mp.nr_direcao, mp.nr_velocidade, mp.nr_dpercorr, mp.nr_azimute, mp.nr_raio, mp.bl_poschave, mp.bl_porta, mp.bl_bloqueado, mp.bl_sirene, mp.bl_setas, mp.bl_panico, mp.bl_excesso_vel, mp.bl_cerca, mp.bl_desenergizado, mp.nr_evento, mp.bl_entrada_1, mp.bl_entrada_2, mp.bl_entrada_3, mp.bl_entrada_4, mp.bl_entrada_5, mp.bl_entrada_6, mp.bl_saida_1, mp.bl_saida_2, mp.bl_saida_3, mp.bl_saida_4, mp.bl_saida_5, mp.bl_saida_6, mp.nr_satelites, mp.bl_ativo, mp.bl_gprs, mp.bl_memory, mp.bl_excesso_rpm, mp.input1, mp.input2, mp.input3, mp.input4, mp.input5, mp.input6, mp.input7, mp.input8, mp.input9
                                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 67kB
                                 ->  Index Scan using mposicao_veiculo_gps on public.mposicao mp  (cost=0.00..115.60 rows=26 width=128) (actual time=0.038..1.054 rows=575 loops=1)
                                       Output: mp.id_posicao, mp.id_veiculo, mp.id_login, mp.id_equip, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor, mp.nr_lat, mp.nr_lon, mp.nr_direcao, mp.nr_velocidade, mp.nr_dpercorr, mp.nr_azimute, mp.nr_raio, mp.bl_poschave, mp.bl_porta, mp.bl_bloqueado, mp.bl_sirene, mp.bl_setas, mp.bl_panico, mp.bl_excesso_vel, mp.bl_cerca, mp.bl_desenergizado, mp.nr_evento, mp.bl_entrada_1, mp.bl_entrada_2, mp.bl_entrada_3, mp.bl_entrada_4, mp.bl_entrada_5, mp.bl_entrada_6, mp.bl_saida_1, mp.bl_saida_2, mp.bl_saida_3, mp.bl_saida_4, mp.bl_saida_5, mp.bl_saida_6, mp.nr_satelites, mp.bl_ativo, mp.bl_gprs, mp.bl_memory, mp.bl_excesso_rpm, mp.input1, mp.input2, mp.input3, mp.input4, mp.input5, mp.input6, mp.input7, mp.input8, mp.input9
                                       Index Cond: ((mp.id_veiculo = 508) AND (mp.dt_gps >= '2014-05-29 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (mp.dt_gps <= '2014-05-29 09:03:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                                       Filter: mp.bl_ativo
 Total runtime: 68726.797 ms
```

But when I remove just the second left join for "mposicao_rastreador" the query takes just 9.041 ms to return the results. Why such great difference?

http://explain.depesz.com/s/9pBV

```
 Limit  (cost=1402.40..293088.75 rows=10 width=228) (actual time=0.304..8.918 rows=10 loops=1)
   Output: mp.id_posicao, mp.id_veiculo, mp.id_login, mp.id_equip, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor, mp.nr_lat, mp.nr_lon, mp.nr_direcao, mp.nr_velocidade, mp.nr_dpercorr, mp.nr_azimute, mp.nr_raio, mp.bl_poschave, mp.bl_porta, mp.bl_bloqueado, mp.bl_sirene, mp.bl_setas, mp.bl_panico, mp.bl_excesso_vel, mp.bl_cerca, mp.bl_desenergizado, mp.nr_evento, mp.bl_entrada_1, mp.bl_entrada_2, mp.bl_entrada_3, mp.bl_entrada_4, mp.bl_entrada_5, mp.bl_entrada_6, mp.bl_saida_1, mp.bl_saida_2, mp.bl_saida_3, mp.bl_saida_4, mp.bl_saida_5, mp.bl_saida_6, mp.nr_satelites, mp.bl_ativo, mp.bl_gprs, mp.bl_memory, mp.bl_excesso_rpm, mp.input1, mp.input2, mp.input3, mp.input4, mp.input5, mp.input6, mp.input7, mp.input8, mp.input9, mt.id_posicao_telemetria, mt.id_posicao, mt.nr_rpm, mt.nr_horimetro, mt.dt_last_update, mt.bl_ativo, mt.id_pessoa, mt.nr_temperatura1, mt.nr_temperatura2, mt.nr_temperatura3, mt.nr_vel_sensor, mt.nr_horimetro_revalidate, mt.nr_gprs_quality, mt.nr_direction, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1402.40..730618.27 rows=25 width=228) (actual time=0.304..8.914 rows=10 loops=1)
         Output: mp.id_posicao, mp.id_veiculo, mp.id_login, mp.id_equip, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor, mp.nr_lat, mp.nr_lon, mp.nr_direcao, mp.nr_velocidade, mp.nr_dpercorr, mp.nr_azimute, mp.nr_raio, mp.bl_poschave, mp.bl_porta, mp.bl_bloqueado, mp.bl_sirene, mp.bl_setas, mp.bl_panico, mp.bl_excesso_vel, mp.bl_cerca, mp.bl_desenergizado, mp.nr_evento, mp.bl_entrada_1, mp.bl_entrada_2, mp.bl_entrada_3, mp.bl_entrada_4, mp.bl_entrada_5, mp.bl_entrada_6, mp.bl_saida_1, mp.bl_saida_2, mp.bl_saida_3, mp.bl_saida_4, mp.bl_saida_5, mp.bl_saida_6, mp.nr_satelites, mp.bl_ativo, mp.bl_gprs, mp.bl_memory, mp.bl_excesso_rpm, mp.input1, mp.input2, mp.input3, mp.input4, mp.input5, mp.input6, mp.input7, mp.input8, mp.input9, mt.id_posicao_telemetria, mt.id_posicao, mt.nr_rpm, mt.nr_horimetro, mt.dt_last_update, mt.bl_ativo, mt.id_pessoa, mt.nr_temperatura1, mt.nr_temperatura2, mt.nr_temperatura3, mt.nr_vel_sensor, mt.nr_horimetro_revalidate, mt.nr_gprs_quality, mt.nr_direction, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor
         ->  Index Scan using id_time_order on public.mposicao mp  (cost=0.00..71365.43 rows=25 width=128) (actual time=0.284..8.770 rows=10 loops=1)
               Output: mp.id_posicao, mp.id_veiculo, mp.id_login, mp.id_equip, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor, mp.nr_lat, mp.nr_lon, mp.nr_direcao, mp.nr_velocidade, mp.nr_dpercorr, mp.nr_azimute, mp.nr_raio, mp.bl_poschave, mp.bl_porta, mp.bl_bloqueado, mp.bl_sirene, mp.bl_setas, mp.bl_panico, mp.bl_excesso_vel, mp.bl_cerca, mp.bl_desenergizado, mp.nr_evento, mp.bl_entrada_1, mp.bl_entrada_2, mp.bl_entrada_3, mp.bl_entrada_4, mp.bl_entrada_5, mp.bl_entrada_6, mp.bl_saida_1, mp.bl_saida_2, mp.bl_saida_3, mp.bl_saida_4, mp.bl_saida_5, mp.bl_saida_6, mp.nr_satelites, mp.bl_ativo, mp.bl_gprs, mp.bl_memory, mp.bl_excesso_rpm, mp.input1, mp.input2, mp.input3, mp.input4, mp.input5, mp.input6, mp.input7, mp.input8, mp.input9
               Index Cond: ((mp.dt_gps >= '2014-05-29 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (mp.dt_gps <= '2014-05-29 09:03:00'::timestamp without time zone))
               Filter: (mp.bl_ativo AND (mp.id_veiculo = 508))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 4671
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.mposicao_telemetria mt  (cost=1402.40..25612.29 rows=75782 width=100) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=10)
               Output: mt.id_posicao_telemetria, mt.id_posicao, mt.nr_rpm, mt.nr_horimetro, mt.dt_last_update, mt.bl_ativo, mt.id_pessoa, mt.nr_temperatura1, mt.nr_temperatura2, mt.nr_temperatura3, mt.nr_vel_sensor, mt.nr_horimetro_revalidate, mt.nr_gprs_quality, mt.nr_direction
               Recheck Cond: (mp.id_posicao = mt.id_posicao)
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on mposicao_telemetria_posicao  (cost=0.00..1383.46 rows=75782 width=0) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=10)
                     Index Cond: (mp.id_posicao = mt.id_posicao)
 Total runtime: 9.041 ms
```

The index configuration of the tables are:

**mposicao**

```
Indexes:
    "mposicao_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id_posicao)
    "id_time_order" btree (dt_gps DESC, dt_servidor DESC)
    "mposicao_equip_gps" btree (id_equip, dt_gps)
    "mposicao_id_equip_idx" btree (id_equip)
    "mposicao_id_veiculo_idx" btree (id_veiculo)
    "mposicao_vec_pos" btree (id_veiculo, id_posicao)
    "mposicao_veiculo_gps" btree (id_veiculo, dt_gps)
    "mposicao_veiculo_gps_pos" btree (id_veiculo, dt_gps, id_posicao)
    "mposicao_veiculo_servidor" btree (id_veiculo, dt_servidor)
    "mpsoicao_vec_equip" btree (id_veiculo, id_equip)
```

**mposicao_telemetria**

```
Indexes:
    "mposicao_telemetria_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id_posicao_telemetria)
    "mposicao_telemetria_posicao" btree (id_posicao)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "cpesfk" FOREIGN KEY (id_pessoa) REFERENCES cpessoa_fisica(id)
    "mposfk" FOREIGN KEY (id_posicao) REFERENCES mposicao(id_posicao)
```

**mposicao_rastreador**

```
Indexes:
    "mposicao_rastreador_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id_posicao_rastreador)
    "mposicao_rastreador_posicao" btree (id_posicao)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "mposfk" FOREIGN KEY (id_posicao) REFERENCES mposicao(id_posicao)
```

I tried to recreate the indexes, extended the work_mem and even performed a vacuum on the tables, but nothing really worked, I just don't know what I'm missing, how two tables that are configured the same way with the same indexes and the same number of rows can relate differently, and the problem is only on the second related table because the problem persists even if I relate just the second table.

My PostgreSQL version:

```
PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc-4.4.real (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1) 4.4.3, 64-bit
```

**UPDATE**:

I tried what Craig said, I reduced random_page_cost from 4.0 to 1.0, and now is taking just 4.146 ms a query that was taking 68726.797 ms, but what is the impact in production with these settings?

```
 Limit  (cost=0.00..547789.51 rows=10 width=269) (actual time=0.211..4.013 rows=10 loops=1)
   Output: mp.id_posicao, mp.id_veiculo, mp.id_login, mp.id_equip, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor, mp.nr_lat, mp.nr_lon, mp.nr_direcao, mp.nr_velocidade, mp.nr_dpercorr, mp.nr_azimute, mp.nr_raio, mp.bl_poschave, mp.bl_porta, mp.bl_bloqueado, mp.bl_sirene, mp.bl_setas, mp.bl_panico, mp.bl_excesso_vel, mp.bl_cerca, mp.bl_desenergizado, mp.nr_evento, mp.bl_entrada_1, mp.bl_entrada_2, mp.bl_entrada_3, mp.bl_entrada_4, mp.bl_entrada_5, mp.bl_entrada_6, mp.bl_saida_1, mp.bl_saida_2, mp.bl_saida_3, mp.bl_saida_4, mp.bl_saida_5, mp.bl_saida_6, mp.nr_satelites, mp.bl_ativo, mp.bl_gprs, mp.bl_memory, mp.bl_excesso_rpm, mp.input1, mp.input2, mp.input3, mp.input4, mp.input5, mp.input6, mp.input7, mp.input8, mp.input9, mt.id_posicao_telemetria, mt.id_posicao, mt.nr_rpm, mt.nr_horimetro, mt.dt_last_update, mt.bl_ativo, mt.id_pessoa, mt.nr_temperatura1, mt.nr_temperatura2, mt.nr_temperatura3, mt.nr_vel_sensor, mt.nr_horimetro_revalidate, mt.nr_gprs_quality, mt.nr_direction, mpr.id_posicao_rastreador, mpr.id_posicao, mpr.nr_voltagem_main, mpr.nr_voltagem_backup, mpr.dt_last_update, mpr.bl_ativo, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..1259915.87 rows=23 width=269) (actual time=0.211..4.011 rows=10 loops=1)
         Output: mp.id_posicao, mp.id_veiculo, mp.id_login, mp.id_equip, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor, mp.nr_lat, mp.nr_lon, mp.nr_direcao, mp.nr_velocidade, mp.nr_dpercorr, mp.nr_azimute, mp.nr_raio, mp.bl_poschave, mp.bl_porta, mp.bl_bloqueado, mp.bl_sirene, mp.bl_setas, mp.bl_panico, mp.bl_excesso_vel, mp.bl_cerca, mp.bl_desenergizado, mp.nr_evento, mp.bl_entrada_1, mp.bl_entrada_2, mp.bl_entrada_3, mp.bl_entrada_4, mp.bl_entrada_5, mp.bl_entrada_6, mp.bl_saida_1, mp.bl_saida_2, mp.bl_saida_3, mp.bl_saida_4, mp.bl_saida_5, mp.bl_saida_6, mp.nr_satelites, mp.bl_ativo, mp.bl_gprs, mp.bl_memory, mp.bl_excesso_rpm, mp.input1, mp.input2, mp.input3, mp.input4, mp.input5, mp.input6, mp.input7, mp.input8, mp.input9, mt.id_posicao_telemetria, mt.id_posicao, mt.nr_rpm, mt.nr_horimetro, mt.dt_last_update, mt.bl_ativo, mt.id_pessoa, mt.nr_temperatura1, mt.nr_temperatura2, mt.nr_temperatura3, mt.nr_vel_sensor, mt.nr_horimetro_revalidate, mt.nr_gprs_quality, mt.nr_direction, mpr.id_posicao_rastreador, mpr.id_posicao, mpr.nr_voltagem_main, mpr.nr_voltagem_backup, mpr.dt_last_update, mpr.bl_ativo, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor
         ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..616585.46 rows=23 width=228) (actual time=0.204..3.968 rows=10 loops=1)
               Output: mp.id_posicao, mp.id_veiculo, mp.id_login, mp.id_equip, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor, mp.nr_lat, mp.nr_lon, mp.nr_direcao, mp.nr_velocidade, mp.nr_dpercorr, mp.nr_azimute, mp.nr_raio, mp.bl_poschave, mp.bl_porta, mp.bl_bloqueado, mp.bl_sirene, mp.bl_setas, mp.bl_panico, mp.bl_excesso_vel, mp.bl_cerca, mp.bl_desenergizado, mp.nr_evento, mp.bl_entrada_1, mp.bl_entrada_2, mp.bl_entrada_3, mp.bl_entrada_4, mp.bl_entrada_5, mp.bl_entrada_6, mp.bl_saida_1, mp.bl_saida_2, mp.bl_saida_3, mp.bl_saida_4, mp.bl_saida_5, mp.bl_saida_6, mp.nr_satelites, mp.bl_ativo, mp.bl_gprs, mp.bl_memory, mp.bl_excesso_rpm, mp.input1, mp.input2, mp.input3, mp.input4, mp.input5, mp.input6, mp.input7, mp.input8, mp.input9, mt.id_posicao_telemetria, mt.id_posicao, mt.nr_rpm, mt.nr_horimetro, mt.dt_last_update, mt.bl_ativo, mt.id_pessoa, mt.nr_temperatura1, mt.nr_temperatura2, mt.nr_temperatura3, mt.nr_vel_sensor, mt.nr_horimetro_revalidate, mt.nr_gprs_quality, mt.nr_direction
               ->  Index Scan using id_time_order on public.mposicao mp  (cost=0.00..17226.86 rows=23 width=128) (actual time=0.192..3.907 rows=10 loops=1)
                     Output: mp.id_posicao, mp.id_veiculo, mp.id_login, mp.id_equip, mp.dt_gps, mp.dt_servidor, mp.nr_lat, mp.nr_lon, mp.nr_direcao, mp.nr_velocidade, mp.nr_dpercorr, mp.nr_azimute, mp.nr_raio, mp.bl_poschave, mp.bl_porta, mp.bl_bloqueado, mp.bl_sirene, mp.bl_setas, mp.bl_panico, mp.bl_excesso_vel, mp.bl_cerca, mp.bl_desenergizado, mp.nr_evento, mp.bl_entrada_1, mp.bl_entrada_2, mp.bl_entrada_3, mp.bl_entrada_4, mp.bl_entrada_5, mp.bl_entrada_6, mp.bl_saida_1, mp.bl_saida_2, mp.bl_saida_3, mp.bl_saida_4, mp.bl_saida_5, mp.bl_saida_6, mp.nr_satelites, mp.bl_ativo, mp.bl_gprs, mp.bl_memory, mp.bl_excesso_rpm, mp.input1, mp.input2, mp.input3, mp.input4, mp.input5, mp.input6, mp.input7, mp.input8, mp.input9
                     Index Cond: ((mp.dt_gps >= '2014-05-29 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (mp.dt_gps <= '2014-05-29 09:03:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                     Filter: (mp.bl_ativo AND (mp.id_veiculo = 508))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 4734
               ->  Index Scan using mposicao_telemetria_posicao on public.mposicao_telemetria mt  (cost=0.00..25289.54 rows=76953 width=100) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=10)
                     Output: mt.id_posicao_telemetria, mt.id_posicao, mt.nr_rpm, mt.nr_horimetro, mt.dt_last_update, mt.bl_ativo, mt.id_pessoa, mt.nr_temperatura1, mt.nr_temperatura2, mt.nr_temperatura3, mt.nr_vel_sensor, mt.nr_horimetro_revalidate, mt.nr_gprs_quality, mt.nr_direction
                     Index Cond: (mp.id_posicao = mt.id_posicao)
         ->  Index Scan using mposicao_rastreador_posicao on public.mposicao_rastreador mpr  (cost=0.00..27134.05 rows=83684 width=41) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=1 loops=10)
               Output: mpr.id_posicao_rastreador, mpr.id_posicao, mpr.nr_voltagem_main, mpr.nr_voltagem_backup, mpr.dt_last_update, mpr.bl_ativo
               Index Cond: (mp.id_posicao = mpr.id_posicao)
 Total runtime: 4.146 ms
```

Comment: It's switching from a simple nested loop to a pair of hash joins. That'd make sense if you weren't throwing away most of the results, but with the limit, it's inefficient. If you significantly lower `random_page_cost` do you get a different result? If, for testing purposes only, you `set enable_seqscan = off; enable_hashjoin=off;` before running your query (do NOT do this in `postgresql.conf` or rely on it in production) does it produce a faster plan?

Comment: BTW 9.2.4 is quite obsolete. Update to the latest 9.2 point release. There are some important bug fixes. It's a simple restart to upgrade, nothing dramatic.

Comment: Personally i'd do the joins after the select, order and limit, should improve it hugely as the join would only be to 10 records...

Comment: Craig I did what you said, I put the result on the question body, it's now taking just 4.146 ms, but what is the impact in production with these settings? On Tony suggestion, I already tried what you said, I had the same thought of limiting first and relating the tables in a wrap, but it didn't make any difference in the performance.

Comment: Looks like the statistics for the id_posicao-columns aren't optimal, that's why the database thinks a sequential scan is faster. Could you show us the results from pg_stats for these tables and columns?